# How to use Azure resource health API in Azure function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a situation where i want to show the Health of my Azure services to the public forum i am trying to architect it something like Azure timer function will get the status of the resources and dump in database which can be displayed by the external App by calling API i tried few stuff but Azure Resource health API is protected by Azure security and which expects the Oauth2 implicit flow which i suppose is initiated in browser and through user interaction is there any way we can bypass this and have simply access the resource health API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure function, we can use Azure MSI to require token then we can call resource health API with the token.

For example

1. [Enable Azure MSI in Azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet#add-a-system-assigned-identity)
2. Assign Azure RABC role Contributor role to the MSI
   [image]
   [image]
3. Code

```
// Install package "Azure.Identity"
private static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        [FunctionName("Function2")]
        public static async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *", RunOnStartup=true)]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
            var creds = new DefaultAzureCredential();
            var scopes = new string[] { "https://management.azure.com/.default" };
            AccessToken token= await creds.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(scopes));
            string uri = " ";
            using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,uri)) {
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.Token);
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request)) {
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
                        var str = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        log.LogInformation(str);
                    }
                }



            }
```